# Does anyone know if Dokan virtual filesystem driver supports file / folder permissions?

Tags: c#, permissions, filesystems, directory, dokan

I'm looking to implement readonly folders into my virtual filesystem which has been created using the Dokan drivers. Does anyone know if setting custom folder permissions is doable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Dokan 0.6.0 you can implement GetFileSecurity and SetFileSecurity callbacks (see https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/blob/master/dokan/dokan.h#L252). I think you can achieve your permissions control with it.